# Cannot convert value of type (CMAccelerometerData!, NSError!) in

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-motion

It keeps saying Cannot convert value of type `(CMAccelerometerData!, NSError!)` . How can I change it?

```
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!, withHandler: {
            (accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData!, error: NSError!) in
            // 3
            let acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration
            // 4
            self.xAcceleration = (CGFloat(acceleration.x) * 0.75) + (self.xAcceleration * 0.25)
            })
```

Comment: Use code-completion. Retype the method. Or type ⇧⌘0 (zero) in the search field and paste `startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue`, then click on `CMAccelerometerHandler` and compare the signatures. A developer must get used to look up the proper method signatures in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Let the compiler infer the types in the closure:

```
CMMotionManager().startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()!) { (accelerometerData, error) in
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
(CMAccelerometerData?, NSError?) -> Void
                    ^         ^
                       not !
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CMAccelerometerHandler)

Comment: I think frameworks that don't have nullability annotations have their variables declared as a force-unwrapped-optional. This might be one of those.